# using regular expression to get strings among commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I am doing some JavaScript coding and have to process a string to a array.

The original string is this: `"red,yellow,blue,green,grey"`

What I want to get is an array like this: `["red","yellow","blue","green","grey"]`

I have tried to write a function to do this, use `indexOf()` to get the position of commas then do some further processing. But I think it's to heavy this way. Is there a better way to use regular expression or some existed JavaScript method to implement my purpose?

Thanks all.

Comment: `split by ,` ?????????????????/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `string.split` function  to split the original string by comma.......

```
string.split(",")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

```
var arr = "red,yellow,blue,green,grey".split(',');
```

**OR**

You can also use [`regex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```
var arr = "red,yellow,blue,green,grey".match(/\w+/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the string.split() method. For further details refer to:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var str = "red,yellow,blue,green,grey";
var res = str.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`.split() function`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

Example

> .split() : Split a string into an array of substrings:

```js
var str = "red,yellow,blue,green,grey";
var res = str.split(",");
alert(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regular expression ..

```
[^,]*
```